# Django Daphne – Database connections max out + "took too long to shut down"

Tags: reactjs, django, server-sent-events, daphne

I'm implementing a messaging system, but experiencing the following two errors on the dev server:

1. "Application instance <...> took too long to shut down and was killed."
2. The database connections get increased on every `new EventSource` that is created, despite it being closed on the frontend.

Here is my code:

Backend:

```
@transaction.non_atomic_requests
async def stream_chat_messages(request: HttpRequest) -> StreamingHttpResponse:

    async def event_stream():
        SLEEP_INTERVAL = 0.3

        """
        We use this function to send a continuous stream of data
        to the connected clients.
        """
        async for message in get_existing_messages():
            yield message

        last_id = await get_last_message_id()

        # Continuously check for new messages
        while True:
            new_messages = _get_messages().filter(id__gt=last_id)
            async for message in new_messages:
                yield f"data: {json.dumps(message)}\n\n"
                last_id = message["id"]
            await asyncio.sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL)

    return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type="text/event-stream")
```

Frontend (React):

```
  const [currentChatroom, setCurrentChatroom] = useState<ChatroomProps | null>(
    null,
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    setMessages([]);

    if (!currentChatroom) return;

    let sse = new EventSource(
      `.../stream-chat-messages/?chatroom=${currentChatroom.id}`,
    );
    sse.onmessage = (event) => {
      // ...
    };
    sse.onerror = () => {
      sse.close();
    };
    
    return () => {
      sse.close();
    };
  }, [currentChatroom?.id]);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Every time the page is loaded, a new database connection is created, but it keeps persisting.

Thanks!